# How can I combine the below 2 sql queries when there are multiple case statements with SUM involved

Tags: sql-server, case

This is the first sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='SELL' THEN (QUANTITY*PRICE) END)  -
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='BUY' THEN (QUANTITY*PRICE) END) AS NET_PL, TRADINGSYMBOL AS STOCK_NAME    
       FROM dbo.[Table1]
       GROUP BY TRADINGSYMBOL, TRADE_DATE
```

This is the second sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='BUY' THEN QUANTITY END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='SELL' THEN QUANTITY END) AS NET_QUANTITY, TRADINGSYMBOL AS STOCK_NAME
       FROM  dbo.[Table1]
       GROUP BY TRADINGSYMBOL
```

This is the query result of second sub-query:

```
NET_QUANTITY           STOCK_NAME
---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
NULL                   ABCL
0                      ADAT
NULL                   BAF
NULL                   BEGE
0                      CRECC
NULL                   CIEN
NULL                   DFMXA
NULL                   DFJL
-50                    HDANK
1000                   MEHD
NULL                   PRAK
0                      TNTS
```

Every TRADINGSYMBOL that exists as part of second query result WITH NET QUANTITY 0 has to be combined/merged with the first query result. I mean apart from TRADINGSYMBOL(s) included in query-1, the query-2 TRADING SYMBOLS also have to get calculated for their (QUANTITY*PRICE) and should be part of final output.

Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be to just treat them as two sub-queries.

```
SELECT
    PL.STOCK_NAME
    ,PL.NET_PL
    ,Q.NET_QUANTITY
FROM
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='SELL' THEN (QUANTITY*PRICE) END)  -
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='BUY' THEN (QUANTITY*PRICE) END) AS NET_PL, TRADINGSYMBOL AS STOCK_NAME    
       FROM dbo.[Table1]
       GROUP BY TRADINGSYMBOL, TRADE_DATE) AS PL
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='BUY' THEN QUANTITY END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRADE_TYPE='SELL' THEN QUANTITY END) AS NET_QUANTITY, TRADINGSYMBOL AS STOCK_NAME
       FROM  dbo.[Table1]
       GROUP BY TRADINGSYMBOL) AS Q ON PL.STOCK_NAME = Q.STOCK_NAME
```

Comment: The final output is still not including the TRADINGSYMBOL values from Sub-Query-2

Comment: If you want everything from both subqueries, use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`